# Having Trouble Hiding an array option in Visual Composer Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

Im attempting to hide an array option in a visual composer dropdown based on the click of a separate checkbox. I am a horrible noob with JS so Ive pieced together this JS to hide the option. Now it does work, but only after an initial cycle through. AKA I have to check the box once then uncheck it to hide the option. And what I need is for the option to not be there by default when the page is loaded.

Again I dont really actually "KNOW" what im doing I just have a basic understanding. So any suggestions on making it more efficient are certainly welcome. If there is anything else info wise that is needed just let me know. Thanks in advance for your time.

PHP for Dropdown Array

```
array(
                          'type'        => 'dropdown',
                          'group'       => __('Animations', 'tt_myfile'),
                          'holder'      => 'div',
                          'heading'     => __("Hover", 'tt_myfile'),
                          'description' => __('Choose your <strong>HOVER</strong> animation', 'tt_myfile'),
                          'param_name'  => "ani_hover",
                          'value'       => array(
                                '--- Please Choose Your Effect ---'     => '',
                                'Curl Bottom Left'       => 'hvr-curl-bottom-left',
                                ),
                          'save_always' => true,
                      ),
```

PHP For CheckBox

```
  array(
                            'group'              => __('Style', 'tt_myfile'),
                            'type'               => 'checkbox',
                            'heading'            => __( 'Flat Design', 'tt_myfile' ),
                            //'admin_enqueue_js' => plugins_url('js/myfile.js', __FILE__), //custom backend JS
                            'param_name'         => 'flat_design',
                            'class'              => 'flat_design',
                            'value'              => array( __( 'Check this box to use flat design.', 'tt_myfile' ) => 'yes' ),
                            ),
```

HTML Output For The Checkbox

```
<label class="vc_checkbox-label">
<input id="flat_design-yes" class="wpb_vc_param_value flat_design checkbox" type="checkbox" name="flat_design" value="yes">
Check this box to use flat design.
</label>
```

JS to Remove/Add The Array Option

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
var myfile_ani_array = {

bind_click: function() {

var flatDesign ='.flat_design';

$(document).on('click', flatDesign, function() {
$(this).change(function () {
var val = false;
$(this).each(function () {
    val = val || $(this).is(':checked'); // any checked box will change val to true
});
jQuery('select[name="ani_hover"] option[value="hvr-curl-bottom-left"]').toggle(val); // true=show, false=hide
});
});

}

};

$(function()
{
    myfile_ani_array.bind_click();

});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on information given:

Html (note i added a new option to show / hide as you only had the only in there)

```
<select data-option="" id="select"  class="wpb_vc_param_value wpb-input wpb-select ani_hover dropdown" name="ani_hover"><option value="" class="">--- Please Choose Your Effect ---</option> <option value="hvr-curl-bottom-left" class="hvr-curl-bottom-left">Curl Bottom Left</option>
<!-- note i am not hiding the original elem, i added a new one, obviously swop the value in the css and js to hide the value you want -->
<option value="hide-this" class="hvr-curl-bottom-left">Curl Bottom another</option>
</select>



<label class="vc_checkbox-label">
<input id="flat_design-yes" class="wpb_vc_param_value flat_design checkbox" type="checkbox" name="flat_design" value="yes" >
Check this box to use flat design.
</label>
```

Hide the element by default with css (note i am targeting the value of the element, i am using "hide-this" for this example to illustrate)

```
.wpb_vc_param_value [value=hide-this]{
    display: none;
}
```

Ok now the value will be hidden by default and on page load we need to check for this (you can also do this with php). One disadvantage of using jquery is you have to wait for the jquery file to load before using, using native js you could remove any lag to hide the element....note place outside your original code

```
//on doc ready run....
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $= jQuery;

    //check if the check box is selected (you can manually test by adding "checked" to the html element 
    // css has the element hidden by default..(see css tab) I have set the value of the element to hide this for an example, you will prob want to modify this, its the value the code checks for. 
    if( $('#flat_design-yes:checked').val() == 'yes' ){
        $('#select > option').each(function(){
            //we are looping over each option 
            if(this.value == 'hide-this'){
                // we have the value we want..
                this.style.display = 'inherit';
            }

        });
    }

});
```

js fiddle (note you can check how it works by adding checked to your checkbox in the html and clicking on run)

http://jsfiddle.net/utwowzkp/14/

Example inside a function:

```
function myCustomDependencyCallback() {

    if( jQuery('#flat_design-yes:checked').val() == 'yes' ){
        jQuery('.ani_hover > option').each(function() {
            // we seem to be hiding all options except the default so if the elem has no value, run..
          if ( this.value.length > 0 && jQuery(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                 jQuery(this).css('display', 'block');
          }
        });
    }
}
```

updated css:

```
.wpb_vc_param_value option{
    display: none;
}

.wpb_vc_param_value option:first-of-type{
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4dvxtgnL/5/

```
if( jQuery('#flat_design-yes:checked').val() == 'yes' ){
        jQuery('.ani_hover > option').each(function(){
            //we are looping over each option 

            if( this.value.match("dont-show$") ){
                // we have the value we want..
                this.style.display = 'block';
                //not sure why but display inherit no longer worked. But display block worked and was friendly with out script for hiding and showing if box is ticked on the fly.
            }

        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to any of param:

```
'dependency' => array(
            'callback' => 'myCustomDependencyCallback',
),
```

then in javascript:

```
function myCustomDependencyCallback() {
   // your actions with hide/show.
   //example:
    $('.flat_design').change(function() {
       var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
       if(checked) {
          $('select[name="ani_hover"]').find('[LIST OF YOUR OPTIONS']).hide();
       } else {
         $('select[name="ani_hover"]').find('[LIST OF YOUR OPTIONS']).show();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Its returning an error TypeError: window[rules.callback] is undefined window[ rules.callback ].call( this );  in /js_composer/assets/js/editors/panels.js?ver=4.8.1 line 1368

Comment: @sean, just because this file doesn't appear to be exists. Be sure that your javascript file loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems everything I had in place was working exactly as it should. I came to the conclusion if the JS was adding an element style once it was clicked to do display none/block. Then I need some default css to be in place for the initial load. So i added this little nugget to my style sheet and all seems to be working excellent. Sort of a De De De moment on my end haha.

```
.vc_shortcode-param[data-param_type="dropdown"] select.wpb_vc_param_value option.hvr-curl-bottom-left {
display: none;
}
```

If anyone knows of any browser compatability issues with everything I have here please dont esitate to comment. Thanks to anyone who took the time to give this a thought. And @David thanks for giving this a shot.

Comment: ****Update***** this only appears to work it seems that JS doesnt know a checkbox is checked on page load, so still it needs to be cycled through to have the change stay. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Ive tried adding `$(document).ready(function () {
$('input.flat_design').each(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    jQuery('select[name="ani_hover"] option[value="hvr-curl-bottom-left"]').css('display', 'block');
}
});
});` to check if its checked on load and no luck..... It works in consol on firebug haha, but then again so does everything else. It just seems no matter what I try this isnt recognizing any of the JS related to the checkbox on the pages initial load